# Since Django update, template rendering throws "'int' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Tags: django

After updating django I am now getting this error in a template rendering:  `int object has no attribute encode`.

I have checked that all of the variables sent to the template are `str()` except for one recordset.

There is no occurrence of the string `encode` anywhere in the template.

The error-stop in debug mode unhelpfully points at a `<meta>` tag at the top of the template.

The error appears to be occurring somewhere *inside* the `render()` call.

The only possibly-significant clue is that one line in the traceback is:

> response = self.process_exception_**by_middleware**(e, request) ...

This software was working normally before the upgrade.  It's now still fairly backwards, parked at Django 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna close this one now because I have trace it to an `el_pagination` library ...

... sorry to have bothered you ...